# Looking for SQL Join

Tags: sql

I have two tables say Educational_Info and Employee_Info. Details of these tables are given below.

Table: Educational_Info

```
DegreeID DegreeName
1 BBA
2 BCA
3 MBA
4 MCA
```

Table: Employee_Info

EmpID BachelorDegree MasterDegree

```
1001 2 4
```

Desired Output:

```
EmpID BachelorDegree MasterDegree
1001 BCA MCA
```

How to get this desired output. If not possible with this table structure, please suggest me any other way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some sample data, and wanted result. Also give us your SQL attemps, and describe whats wrong with it. Employee_Info left join Educational_Info twice.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far. StackOverflow is a site where you post questions about a problem you are having, not a list of requirements expecting others to do your work. So have you tried to solve this yourself and ran into a problem? What error did you get? Can you show some code?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT E.Empid,EI1.DegreeName,EI2.DegreeName 
FROM Employee_info E 
  INNER JOIN Educational_Info EI1 ON E.BachelorDegree=EI1.Degreeid
  INNER JOIN Educational_Info EI2 ON E.MasterDegree=EI2.Degreeid
```

Comment: Outer join, if someone has only 1 degree.

Comment: Mark this answer correct if you find it helpful. you needed to make join two times with the table.

Answer (score 1):

This this. This gives you some idea

```
select b.EmpID,a.DegreeName
FROM Educational_Info a
JOIN Employee_Info b on b.BachelorDegree = a.DegreeID or b.MasterDegree = a.DegreeID
```

Comment: Outer join, if someone has only 1 degree